# Match elements by name / alt tag and get corresponding data

Tags: jquery, json

EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION---

I have a blog that will have images that I would like to automatically link to store products based off an array that would be created by Shopify.

I'm not completely versed when it comes to jQuery and JSON, but I feel like this must be something that can be done. Any pointers? I don't expect the entire code to be written but any help is great.

Each image will be placed in more or less as follows (pre-data-population from the JSON output):

```
<a href="">
<span class="title-overlay"><span>
<img alt="PRODUCT TITLE" src="/images/image.jpg">
</a>
```

JSON output is like this:

```
{"products":[{
"id":6392068867,
"title":"Avignon",
"vendor":"FBRC 04",
"product_type":"Jackets",
"created_at":"2016-05-02T11:10:09-07:00",
"handle":"avignon",
"updated_at":"2016-10-31T11:41:25-07:00",
"published_at":"2016-01-04T15:16:00-08:00",
"template_suffix":"",
"published_scope":"global",
"tags":"",
}]}
```

The image would be given the alt tag of "Avignon" by the user of the blog.
jQuery would recognize this, and then recognize the corresponding object from the JSON output by matching it with the "title" attribute (as above).

Then jQuery would populate the < a > tag "href" attribute with the "handle" attribute from the JSON object.

Then jQuery would populate the < span > innerHTML with the "title" attribute from the JSON object.

**And here is a diagram to illustrate:**
[image]

Comment: I don't understand this question, but definitely don't use the "alt" attribute for this.  The "alt" attribute is an accessability feature for providing a text description of an image for those users unable to see images.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you can use [data-attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for better performance and consistency. Store the thing you want to compare using jQuery in `data-*` attribute and use it in your way.

Comment: Thanks. This may be part of the battle for me. I did clarify the original question a bit and would appreciate any other help if you feel so inclined. Thanks again!